# race conditiion arises in Spring boot restful api using hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-rest

Here is my controller and api :-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insertData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public  ResponseEntity<?> insertTransaction(@Valid @RequestBody Params requestParams,
        BindingResult results) {
    Map<String, String> responseMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    transactionService.insertTransaction(requestParams);
    return new ResponseEntity<Transactions>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Following is my service class's method having `@Transactional` annotation on class level. Here I need to insert a row in the table. But before that I'm fetching latest value from db by using this method mentioned in code  [getBalance()]. Now according to this value my table's columns will be updated (last line here in code) `dao.insert(Entity)`

```
public ResponseDTO insert(ReequestParams request) {
    Entity entity = new entity();
    List<?> list = null;
    request.setCurrTranPrevBal(getBalance(bEntity, loggedInUserId, opponentUserId));
    setCurrentPaymentStatus(request);

    BeanUtils.copyProperties(request, entity );

    entity .setTransactionId(transactionId());
    entity .setCreatedBy(entity .getInitiatedFrom());
    Date date = DateUtils.getCurrentDateTime();
    entity .setPaymentDate(date);
    entity .setCreatedOn(date);
    entity .setModifiedOn(date);
    entity .setModifiedBy(entity .getInitiatedFrom());

bEntity=balanceDAO.getByBothUsersId(entity .getPayerId(),
      transactionEntity.getPayeeId());


    } else {
        updatePendingTransactionAmount(entity , bEntity);


    saveUsersItems(entity );

    list = transactionDao.insert(entity );

    ResponseDTO dto = copyInResponseDto(list);
    return dto;
}

private void updatePendingAmount(Entity entity,
        BalanceEntity balanceEntity) {
    int payerId = entity.getPayerId();
    BigDecimal skyCredit = entity.getSkyCredit();
    BigDecimal pendingAmount = bEntity.getPendingAmount();

    bEntity.setPendingTransactionAmount(pendingAmount);
    bEntity.setModifiedOn(DateUtils.getCurrentDateTime());
    bEntity.setModifiedBy(transactionEntity.getInitiatedFrom());
    bEntity.setTransacted(true);

}
```

But when multiple http requests hits the api (load testing) , then insertion is done before reading the latest value. What I want is transaction must be inserted after reading the latest value. Insertion must be done one by one.
I tried synchronized block too and also isolatio levels but not working.
Here we are updating two tables by `usersBalanceDAO` and `transactionDao`.
Please help me implementing lock or synchronization if neeed here or is there any architectural issue .

Comment: Do you have @EnableTransactionManagement configuration?

Comment: Also, try to increase isolation level of transactions, for example, @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE), you probably have a low level.

Comment: yes .  I have enabled the transaction mangement on class level. by @Transactional on class. I also tried Isolation on method level as you mentioned  above. i am having two singleton objects balanceDao and transactionDao to update two tables. I hope there shouldn't be issue of these..

Comment: i also have used getCurrentSession() method for session instance and not closing session factory so do i need to open a new session evrytime for unit of work..

Comment: Transactional and EnableTransactionManagement are not the same - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations.